# DNS mapping to subfolders

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain, forwarding, cname

I have a use case where I have DNS domain with name www.example.com which points to test.com/abcd .

Now I want to create one more dns record which should point www.example.com/test2 to 
test2.com/abcd.

www.example.com is just a domain name and I dont have any server running on it.

Comment: Could you please show your DNS records at www.example.com and test.com that implement your initial setup?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a `CNAME` record like so:

```
www.example.com   CNAME   test.com
```

And code on `test.com` that performs a redirect, probably for all resources at `www.example.com`:

```
if (req.headers['Host'] === 'www.example.com') {
    res.writeHead(301, { 'Location': 'http://test.com/abcd' + req.url });
    res.end();
}
```

Since `www.example.com` is served by `test.com`, then you need to include another redirect on the server, which can either happen when clients land at `http://www.example.com/test2` or when they land at `http://test2.com/abcd/test2`.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask for called URL forwarding, and **not** DNS records. DNS records point to IP addresses or to another DNS records and test.com/abcd is neither of these. test.com is a domain name (DNS record), test.com/abcd is not a domain name, but it is an URL.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do this with DNS directly. DNS can only map to an host, but not path / port.

You will need a web server to redirect by HTTP 301. If you have access to edit your DNS record [here](http://redirect.200please.com/) is an easy one. You can also setup your own Apache / IIS if you are familiar with those rules.

Just remember HTTP 301 is a must to redirect otherwise your pageranks can't be transferred completely